# Redux does not load the api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux

Redux newbie here.

I am following a Udemy course on Redux and I am building a 'robofriends' app, that fetches data from an api and returns it back in my app.

I have followed the course but right at the end, there are no bugs but the content does not load. It is just stuck on loading.

In the developer console, I can see with Redux that the app has successfully fetched the data from the API, but it just will not display it.

Here is the code in question:

**

- ACTIONS:

**

```js
import {
  CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD,
  REQUEST_ROBOTS_PENDING,
  REQUEST_ROBOTS_SUCCESS,
  REQUEST_ROBOTS_FAILED
} from "./constants";

export const setSearchField = text => ({
  type: CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD,
  payload: text
});

export const requestRobots = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: REQUEST_ROBOTS_PENDING });
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .then(data => dispatch({ type: REQUEST_ROBOTS_SUCCESS, payload: data }))
    .catch(error => dispatch({ type: REQUEST_ROBOTS_FAILED, payload: error }));
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**

- REDUCER:

**

```js
import {
  CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD,
  REQUEST_ROBOTS_PENDING,
  REQUEST_ROBOTS_SUCCESS,
  REQUEST_ROBOTS_FAILED
} from "./constants.js";
//INITIAL STATE
const initialStateSearch = {
  searchField: ""
};

//SEARCHROBOTS PURE FUNCTION (React docs recommends switch statements)
export const searchRobots = (state = initialStateSearch, action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD:
      //Returning a new state and assign action.payload to the new searchField
      return Object.assign({}, state, { searchField: action.payload });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const initialStateRobots = {
  isPending: false,
  robots: [],
  error: ""
};

export const requestRobots = (state = initialStateRobots, action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST_ROBOTS_PENDING:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { isPending: true });
    case REQUEST_ROBOTS_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        robot: action.payload,
        isPending: false
      });
    case REQUEST_ROBOTS_FAILED:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        error: action.payload,
        isPending: false
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**

- APP

**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Cardlist from "../components/Cardlist";
import SearchBox from "../components/SearchBox";
import "./App.css";
import Scroll from "../components/Scroll";
import { ButtonToolbar } from "react-bootstrap";
import { setSearchField, requestRobots } from "../actions.js";

//State to listen for
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    searchField: state.searchRobots.searchField,
    robots: state.requestRobots.robots,
    isPending: state.requestRobots.isPending,
    error: state.requestRobots.error
  };
};

//State to listen for and dispatch
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onSearchChange: event => dispatch(setSearchField(event.target.value)),
    onRequestRobots: () => dispatch(requestRobots())
  };
};

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onRequestRobots();
  }

  render() {
    const { searchField, onSearchChange, robots, isPending } = this.props;
    const filteredRobots = robots.filter(robot => {
      return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase());
    });
    return !isPending ? (
      <h1>Loading</h1>
    ) : (
      <div className="tc">
        <h1 className="f1">Robofriends</h1>
        <SearchBox searchChange={onSearchChange} />
        <Scroll>
          <Cardlist robots={filteredRobots} />
        </Scroll>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//'Connect' connects this app container to the redux state
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

- **INDEX FILE**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider, connect } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from "redux";
import { createLogger } from "redux-logger";
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./containers/App.js";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { searchRobots, requestRobots } from "./reducers";
import "tachyons";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const logger = createLogger();
const rootReducer = combineReducers({ searchRobots, requestRobots });
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, logger)
);

ReactDOM.render(
  //Provides store to all components
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

   
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**

- CONSOLE WINDOW:

[image]

**

So it is supposed to display this:

[How it is supposed to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OnXc.gif)

But instead it is just stuck on this:

[Cannot get past the loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XfM9.jpg)

Can anyone help me with this one? I hope it's all clear!

Thank you

Comment: I just want to know why are you not using `create-react-app` or `react-boilerplate`?

Comment: I am just following an introduction course, I used create-react-app to create the app though?

Comment: I am happy now :)

Comment: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users is unreachable, so just make sure you can reach it then try again. So far your code looks ok.

Comment: @JothamArdel Thank you!!

Comment: @DanDyson you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

where is your index.js file ......?

Did you connect reducer  to root reducer because you are doing well otherwise.. or share developer console wndow or error type

Comment: Study Mania,

I have included index.js and console in the original post, thanks for pointing that out.

I have the rootReducer on there - any thoughts on what it could be? I dont think its the API..

Comment: Its look like promisr sync problem

Comment: How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: sync problem you can solve with async when you function body need to wait for particular process but we know that java script is single thread and quee based language thats why you cant perform without async ..... So the answer is " const function = async () => {... function bdy .....  const sync = await you variable value } "
but i think you can solve this error with just if condition put this condition . query ? "perform your action"  :  void 0